# Opening a 20GB file for analysis with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, anaconda, data-science

i am new to data Science and Dta Analytics i hope my question is not too naive. I am currently trying to open a file with pandas and python  for machine learning purposes it would be ideal for me to have them all in a  DataFrame. Now   The file is 18GB large and my RAM is 32 GB but i keep getting  memory errors.

1. from your experience is it possible?
2. if not do you know know of a better to way to go around this? (hive table? increase the size of my RAM to 64? create a database and access it from python)
   Every input will be welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best practice aside, are you using 64bit Python? 32-bit Python has a 2GB memory limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: Related: [“Large data” work flows using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262433/190597)

Comment: The duplicate is for a smaller file size but the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: Jupyter QtConsole 4.3.1
Hey Stev thanks for your answer i am working within Anaconda (64Bits ) Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?'

Answer (score 0):

You should try read and process one predefined chunk of data each time
by using chunksize as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053628/open-selected-rows-with-pandas-using-chunksize-and-or-iterator)

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, sep = ' ', header = None, chunksize = 512):
         # process your chunk here
```

Comment: Thanks Gal ben actually i cannot do my analysis in chunks.But  you gave me a good idea here and i'm trying it out . So actually i am preprocessing the data in chunks first so i can reduce the amount o records  and create  a shorter excel filf from which a can derive a better dataframe.

Comment: Np! Good luck :) Btw, The reason you get memory exceptions is because the loaded data is bigger in the memory than it’s on the disk. Pandas does some processing on the data in order do achieve fast querying and aggregation which makes it use much more memory than the raw file

Answer (score 0):

Can you work with the data in chunks? If so you can use the iterator interface of pandas to go through the file.

```
df_iterator = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, iterator=True, chunksize=5)
for df in df_iterator:
    print(df)
    # do something meaningful
    print('finished iteration on {} rows'.format(df.shape[0]))
    print()
```